# Using particls to simulate automatic gunfire Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, parent

The situation is i have a few gun models that i will use in a scene where there are a lot of them and they all need to be able to fire bullets easily without me animating each bullet as these are automatic weapons.
So i have a gun and i made a simple bullet that i want to use as a particle system for automatic gunfire.

So i have this bullet model right inside the bore of the gun and i parented the bullet mesh to the gun. I then added a particle system to the bullet that used the bullet model as the particle in the render tab. A couple problems arose such as the particles not appearing, they have far too much drop due to gravity especially in the case of a rocket launcher that needs to go slowly but not drop. and i also don't understand how to turn them on and off such as in a burst fire situation so it fires then stops then starts firing again.

Comment: You can reduce gravity influence for particles, iirc... and yoy could animate the particle emission on/off, I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple test that shows how you could defy gravity and animate particles to "gunfire" bullets:

[image]

this setup  could work like this:

[image]

here is a test blend file:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much i had no idea what Gra was

Comment: oh, That is just the slider label that is shortened by lack of panel width...

Comment: @m.ardito how would you pick the time of where it fires? How does that F-Curve work?

Comment: @AlexSandoval the F-curve is animating the emitter object velocity along the X axis only. it goes nearly instantly fro 0 to 20, for a while, then it goes back to 0. Since the gravity field weights effect is 0, the emitted particles do not fall down. I added a test file (created with 2.79 but still seems to work until 2.90). I hope this helps you to understand what's happening